# How to get vertices of feature in geotools

Tags: geotools

Could anybody show me how to get vertices of feature by java geotools api?

In my case, i have a polygon layer in postgis, i can query all feature of this layer and i need to know vertices of each feature.

```
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = pgDatastore.getFeatureSource("hb_thuadat");
        Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("sothua = 10");
        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures( filter );
        System.out.print("tong so:"+ collection.size());

        FeatureIterator iter=collection.features();
        while( iter.hasNext() ){
            Feature feature = iter.next();
            System.out.println( feature.getIdentifier());
            //how to get vertices of feature here???
        }
```

Any help is appreciate! Thank!

Answer (score 5):

By converting your `feature` object to `SimpleFeature` type you should be able to extract geometry value like following:

```
SimpleFeature sp = DataUtilities.simple(feature);
Geometry geom = (Geometry) sp.getDefaultGeometry();
```

Vertices can be retrieved like the following:
`Coordinate[] array_of_coords = geom.getCoordinates();`
`System.out.println(array_of_coords[0].x);//X Coordinate`
`System.out.println(array_of_coords[0].y);//Y Coordinate`

Answer (score 0):

I find solution my self by this code

```
            Feature feature = iter.next();
            SimpleFeature sfeature = (SimpleFeature)feature;
            Geometry g = (Geometry)sfeature.getAttribute("the_geom");
            // System.out.print(g.getCoordinates().length);
            Coordinate coor = g.getCoordinate();
            System.out.println("x: " + coor.x);
            System.out.println("y: " + coor.y);
```